# Extract first two characters after trailing slash using regex

Tags: regex

I can extract all characters after the trailing slash of an url using this regex:

```
([^/]*)$
```

How can I extract only the first two characters after the trailing slash? I want to use it within Google Data Studio.

Comment: `[^/]{2}(?=[^/]*$)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe some simple lookahead and lookbehind.

```
(?<=\/)..(?!.*\/)
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qxjbeh/1)

Or:

```
\/\K..(?!.*\/)
```

See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qxjbeh/2)

---

If you want to be more verbose/explicit, maybe change `..` into `[^\/]{2}`.

---

**Update:** You now mentioned you are using Google Data Studio. Lookarounds won't work in that case. Have a try with:

```
([^\/]{2})[^\/]*$
```

And grab the 1st capture group. See the [demo](https://regex101.com/r/qxjbeh/3)

Comment: Thanks, I guess, this solution works fine when I look at the demo. However, in Google Data Studio it doesn't work. I forgot to mention that I want to use it in Google Data Studio.

Comment: @HansOlo, maybe try `([^\/]{2})[^\/]*$` in GDS and take the 1st capture group.

Comment: almost. I've just learned that Iyou need to double escape special characters with two backslashes in Google Data Studio. This works fine: ([^\\/]{2})[^\\/]*$